# Anchor links don't work on pages with query strings

Tags: hyperlink, query-string, anchor

I've become dumbfounded by this. This might be something that I've just assumed worked all along, but in fact has never worked.

I've got an anchor link on a page `<a href="#activities">[Activities]</a>` and later on the page I have the anchor `<a name="activities"></a>`. This is the URL of the page: https://iassid.org/index.php?option=com_content&id=216

For some reason, the anchor link on the page brings the user back to https://iassid.org/index.php#activities

Has removing the query string always been normal behavior? The href in the anchor tag doesn't include anything but the hash, why would it even assume to go off the page? Why does it go back to the original URL without the query string? Is there any way to get this to work without putting the entire URL including the query string in the URL as well? I'm trying to make this easy for someone who isn't very familiar with HTML, so using onclick events and other options aren't desired.

Maybe I've just been crazy to assume this would work all along! Thanks for any insights.

Comment: it isn't removing the query string, it is actually triggering a page change. Do you have javascript listening on that element that could be redirecting?

Comment: The sight is running in Joomla! 1.5.17 so maybe. When I hover over the link I see the URL it will leads to, and it's https://iassid.org/index.php#activities, which is just the same thing with the query string removed. I have just never heard of javascript causing links to anchors triggering a page change and removing the query string... so strange.

Comment: Take a look at http://www.g4v.com/support/faqs/3-joomla-support/5-how-do-i-create-targets-a-anchors-in-joomla.html

Comment: Thanks Bot. That was the process that as being used to create the anchor and link, but it still doesn't work. I've looked at the HTML involved and validated it as well and seen nothing that looks like it would cause this. I have tried removing scripts as well with no luck. Must be a Javascript / Joomla! thing but I can't seem to figure out what or why.